# How can I transcribe incoming voice from a video call to text in a Chrome extension created using React Webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-extension, speech-to-text

I am working on a Chrome extension using React and Webpack, aimed at creating notes of calls made through video conferencing platforms. I have successfully implemented transcription of outgoing voice using the react-speech-recognition library, but I'm facing difficulties with transcribing incoming voice.

Here's a brief overview of what I have so far:

- I've created a Chrome extension that interacts with video calls in the browser.
- Outgoing voice transcription is achieved using the react-speech-recognition library, and it's working as expected.

Now, I need to transcribe incoming voice during video calls. I understand that I might need to capture audio from the incoming stream, but I'm unsure about the best approach and how to integrate this with my Chrome extension.

Has anyone dealt with a similar situation or have insights on how to capture and transcribe incoming voice from a video call in a Chrome extension using React and Webpack? I'm open to any suggestions, code examples, or guidance on how to approach this problem effectively.

Thank you in advance for your help!